# Unique entry verification using MySQL and PHP

Tags: php, mysql, database, select

I need to verify that a user registering for a website enters a unique 16 digit number that no one else prior to him/her has entered.

The relevant database information is that the 16 digit numbers are stored in a column called `card1`, the name of the entire table is `users`, and the user-entered number is stored in `$card1`.

Here is what I have so far...

```
$query2 = "SELECT card1 FROM users WHERE card1='$card1' LIMIT 1";
$result2 = smart_mysql_query($query2);

if (mysql_num_rows($result2) != 0)
{               
    header ("Location: register.php?msg=exists");
    exit();
}
```

The idea is that it will find any examples already in the database and if it finds a duplicate, it will display and error message.

The problem is that it is continuing to allow users to register(submit their registration form to the db) even when there is a duplicate. Immediately after this block of code is the insertion call to the db with all of the user information collected from the form.

**NOTE:** I'm not very familiar with handling PHP error messages and what I've used is just an example that I found in another instance in the example code.

Answer (score 3):

Make the if statement like this:

```
$query2 = "SELECT * FROM users WHERE card1='$card1'";
$result2 = mysql_query($query2);

if ($result2 !== false)
{               
   header ("Location: register.php?msg=exists");
   exit();
}
```

Should fix the problem:)

Comment: I've tried both versions of you answer and it hasn't worked yet. what does the different if statement accomplish?

Comment: When the mysql database returns 0 rows the php script will give you a boolean which will be set to false. This if statement will check if the result of the query is false and if it is throw the error.

Comment: Try the new piece of code. I changed the query a little and the smart_mysql_query is now mysql_query

Comment: I tried the new query as well with no success. The new user account is still created and they are navigated to a new page successfully.

Comment: hmmm could you do a `var_dump($_POST)` or `var_dump($_GET)` to see what is given by the form/user? Maybe the `$card1` variable doesnt get set properly?

Comment: you'll have to elaborate. I'm don't understand what you mean. I know with certainty that what the user has entered is passed correctly into the database and that the card number this test user has entered is not unique since there is already a user with the same card number stored in the db.

Comment: have you confirmed that the number that you entered is also added in the database and it is completely the same as the previous one? Also what is this 'smart_mysql_query'? i have never heard of it have you tried without the 'smart_' part?.

Comment: yes, the number is exactly the same.

also, the smart is just what I have picked up from the other code on the page. I am not familiar with php or mysql really but I've been trying to pick apart the syntax to gain an understanding of the problem.

Comment: Have you tried my solution with a normal mysql_query (so without the smart_)?

Comment: yes. I've tried all of your solutions without luck. Thanks for you help so far though.

Comment: Im sorry but i can't see what is going wrong from the bit of code you have given me. It seems to be allright to me.

Answer (score 2):

The correct way to do this is to add a unique index on the field that holds the number that the use has entered (`card1`).

You will then try and `INSERT` the new row without trying to `SELECT` it first, and if this operation fails you redirect the user to the `msg=exists` page. This lets the database handle the duplicate detection and removes the problem inherent in your method - if two users submit the same number at the same time, there is no guarantee that `SELECT` -> `INSERT` will detect it. A unique index will detect and prevent this.

This will also have the advantage of reducing database traffic, since only one query is executed in order to get this happen.

Comment: While this solution would work, one issue with it is that it becomes difficult to determine why the INSERT statement failed and return a meaningful message to the user depending on that error state

Comment: is this idea similar to the answer that @rkosegi posted below?

Comment: @AndreLackmann I don't know if it would pose that much of a problem. Wouldn't there only be the possibility that there already was a user with the same number in there and I can just notify the user of that and have them resubmit another?

Comment: @Mike - sure in a very simplistic manner. I'm not saying you're wrong, just that it wouldn't be best practise IMHO. I say this as you might have other fields in the user table that have similar constraints (a UNIQUE index on an email field perhaps). If this is the case and your query fails, you can't easily determine which constraint caused the INSERT to bork. That said, change the corresponding INSERT to an UPDATE and you have a more specific solution

Comment: @AndreLackmann Fair enough. I actually do have a working example of email verification for the same form but the problem is approached in the same manner as my code above. In fact, that I used the structure as a model for how to handle the number uniqueness issue.

Comment: @Mike - sure.. I voted for rkosegi's solution because you really need to do both. That is, have the UNIQUE index and do a check. That will ensure you avoid any race condition where two processes attempt to use the same $card1 value virtually simultaneously. Both check at the same time and find the # is available. The first to UPDATE/INSERT will success, the second will fail. Unlikely, but possible.

Comment: @AndreLackmann Ok. Thanks. I will attempt to hack out a solution with a bit of Google-fu.

Comment: @DaveRandom How do I determine whether or not the insertion fails?

Comment: Just check the result of `mysql_query()` as a boolean. It will return `TRUE` on success, and `FALSE` on failure.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, create unique index in DB on this column.
This is best practice:

```
ALTER TABLE `users`
ADD UNIQUE INDEX `card1` (`card1`);
```

I should modify your SQL as follows:

```
$query2 = "SELECT COUNT(1) FROM users WHERE card1='$card1'";
$res = mysql_query($query2);

$data = mysql_fetch_array($res);

if ($data == 1)
{               
   header ("Location: register.php?msg=exists");
   exit();
}
```

It will check for existence of row within table and return 0 or 1.

If exists (1) then it will redirect you.

Comment: Where is the `$res` coming from?

Answer (score 0):

try this one

```
$query2 = "SELECT card1 FROM users WHERE card1='".$card1."' LIMIT 1";
$result2 = mysql_query($query2);

if (mysql_num_rows($result2) > 0)
{               
    header ("Location: register.php?msg=exists");
    exit();
}
```